# How do I set Basecamp credentials using apple IOS for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, basecamp

I'm trying to request my company's Basecamp info for an internal project we're building. I understand how to add credentials in an ASP.NET environment but I'm new to iPad development and can't seem to get an appropriate response from Basecamp. Here's what I'm doing:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mybasecampname.basecamphq.com/projects.xml"]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0 ];
```

I'm adding the HTTP headers that Bsaecamp requires like so:

```
[theRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" ];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept" ];
```

I know I also need to send my credentials for authentication purposes - my authentication token and any password I like but I'm not sure the best way to do this. Here's what I'm trying:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"MY TOKEN HERE"
                                                             password:@"x"
                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

My question is: Am I on the right track here or am I missing something completely?

Here's a link to the Basecamp API details which explains what it needs: http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/

Help appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 5):

As is always the way, I worked it out eventually. Once I started using the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method things started to fall into place.

So. I simplified my request method:

```
- (void)startRequest
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mybasecampproject.basecamphq.com/projects.xml"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Start the connection request
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    }
```

and then set up a method for receiving the authentication challenge:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"Authentication challenge..."); 

    NSURLCredential *cred = [[[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"my basecamp token here" password:@"X"
                                                           persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] autorelease];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}
```

then set up a didReceiveData method to catch the data returned:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Did receive data"); 

    NSString * strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(strResult);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Still happy to hear better method for this

JJ