# Getting token for userid and password in basecamp api

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, token, basecamp

I want to use BaseCamp API in my ipad application. I will ask user to enter username and password but each request requires authentication token. Please tell me how to get user token having username and password of user.
Please help.

Comment: You can first tell us what you have tried and where are u stuck.

Comment: I have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913269/how-do-i-set-basecamp-credentials-using-apple-ios-for-ipad